# Don't show background image when exporting to Excel in SSRS

Tags: c#, .net, sql, excel, reporting-services

Apparently when exporting a SQL Server Reporting Services document to Excel XLS any background image that you've included is tiled across the whole spreadsheet and not just placed neatly up in the top corner like is shown in the Report Viewer.

Does anyone know of any work arounds that would either:

A) Don't show the background at all in XLS only

B) Show the image once up in the corner like is done in the viewer (first image)

[image: Proper Background]

But Excel is giving me this!! It looks terrible.
[image: Excel Tiling glitch]

Comment: The only workaround I've really found also is to just pad the image itself with ridiculous amounts of white space and just use that version. The image still tiles of course just it's less noticable.

Comment: What version of SSRS? SSRS 2008 R2 adds some functionality to help with this. I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

SSRS 2008R2 added a function to help with this sort of scenario.

I haven't used this much, but this formula should change the background image if you are rendering to Excel:

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name ="EXCEL", "", "MyBackgroundImageName")
```

Here's a blog with [more details on RenderFormat](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robertbruckner/archive/2010/05/02/globals-renderformat-aka-renderer-dependent-report-layout.aspx).

Comment: I have SSRS 2008 but I'll give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: I think this was added with R2. (R2 was a pretty big update for SSRS.) So I don't think it will work for you on 2008.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you're right RenderFormat does not appear to exist on 2008.

Comment: I'm having another weird issue with excel not doing the groupings correctly but I'll post another question for that.